# Different Labels if Field Contains Specific Text (VBScript)

Tags: labeling, vbscript

I have a `NAME` field for multiple assets: `Tanks`, `Reservoirs`, `Pump Stations`, etc. Currently, I have everything labeled using the following script:

```
[NAME] & vbNewLine & [Vol_Mgal] + " " + "Mgal"
```

I would like to include the `elevation` for just those that contain the word `Tank`. Is there a way to do this using script?

Here is my latest attempt:

```vb
Function FindLabel ([NAME], [ADDRESS])    
  if (cLng([ADDRESS]) = "TANK" then
    FindLabel = [NAME] & vbNewLine & [Vol_Mgal] + " " + "Mgal" + "," & [ELEVATION]+"ft"
 else
     FindLabel = [NAME] & vbNewLine & [Vol_Mgal] + " " + "Mgal"
 end if
End Function
```

Results: "Carriage returns are not allowed in simple expressions."

Comment: Is Elevation an attribute of your data, if not you will need to bring it into your dataset. Also good practise to include screen shots of your data as my first question would be elevation of what, donuts on Mars? You also neglect to say what software you are using? State that and add the tag.

Comment: Elevation is an attribute of my data.

Comment: This line is nonsense - `if (cLng([ADDRESS]) = "TANK" then`. You are converting address to a number and trying to compare a number to the text "TANK".